# How To get Cookies from this strange Domain?

Tags: c#, http, cookies

Hey guys, I have a problem. 
I have situation where domain in m_domainTable starts with "." (dot), how can I get cookies from this kinda domain ? I can't create Uri with for example http://.testdomain.com

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/1817/questionh.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/1817/questionh.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just using some dummy text in front of the domain.  `http://dummy.testdomain.com`

The . prefix indicates that the cookie is valid for any sub-domain or host inside the testdomain.

Comment: Thanks, You saved my life :D and I'm stupid that I did't tried smth like that before :)